# Turning multiple dbms query responses into the same type of variable (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, postgresql, rdbms

I am making a function (PHP). In this function it basically uses the dbms specified and connects, submits the appropriate query, <insert my problem here>, and disconnects. DBMSs include MySQL, MSSQL, Postgres, and Oracle.

I am assuming that outside of this function, the user would not have access to specified DMBS, so whatever results I get from it I need to convert to something usable like a regular PHP variable/array/object.

I don't know the best way to do this (and have only had extended experience with MySQL), so I would like to know how going about handling each return so that they all come out to PHP relatively the same. I would extremely appreciate an example in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are doing this to learn, I recommend looking into [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo). It comes built in since PHP 5, and can handle the DBMSs you mention.

There's also [ADODb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) that supports even more DBMSs but has the disadvantage of not being a native, compiled part of PHP.

In my opinion, it's not worth writing an own database wrapper anymore in 2010 for production use. There are too many high-quality industry-standard solutions around.